# Simple contract throws for no apparent reason

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas, ropsten, error

the thing is that i have a very simple contract code that I wrote as a kind of "Hello World!", but it doesn't seem to work properly, and I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

The code I'm talking about is this one:

```
pragma solidity >0.4.18;

contract TimedSafe {

    address creator;
    address bank = 0xB599C8008E505ed9bd34C4761EBAae53a89207Af;

    uint256 safe;

    uint256 startTime;
    uint256 endTime;

    uint8 state; 

    /* Constructor */
    constructor() public {
        creator = msg.sender;
        state = 0;
    }

    function storeSafe(uint8 m) public payable {
        assert(msg.sender == creator);
        assert(state == 0);
        safe = msg.value;
        startTime = now;
        endTime = startTime + (m * 1 minutes);
        state = 1;
    }

    function retrieveSafe() public {
        assert(msg.sender == creator);
        assert(state == 1);
        if(now < endTime) {
            state = 2;
            creator.transfer(safe);
        } else {
            state = 3;
            bank.transfer(safe);
        }
    }

    function timeLeft() public view returns (uint256 t) {
        assert(state == 1);
        return endTime - now;
    }

    function getState() public view returns (uint8 st) {
        return state;
    }
}
```

The function that doesn't work properly is "retrieveSafe".
I deployed this contract on the Ropsten testnet, just in case it is of importance.

Comment: If you can share a link to the failed transaction on Ropsten, it's likely possible for someone to tell you exactly what went wrong. Otherwise we just have to speculate as to which of the `require`s or `transfer`s is failing.

Comment: @smarx Of course, here it is: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xca594ca981a3e492baa728cc26363f09552b9d21c40c54415fa52bb7392f96a5

Comment: The input data for that transaction is just `0x`, so you didn't call any function. How are you attempting to call `retrieveSafe`? Are you using a tool? If so, what? Are you writing code? If so, please share the code.

Comment: @smarx The only code I wrote is posted here. And about the `0x` input, I don't really know why it's like that, I'm only using the Mist wallet tool for calling functions on the contracts, and it does "everything" by itself.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used Mist for anything, but it would seem there's a bug there. I can tell you with confidence that the transaction you sent is _not_ calling `retrieveSafe` and is instead just invoking the function's fallback function (which doesn't exist and therefore reverts). Either figure out how to get Mist to send a valid transaction or switch to another tool.

Comment: @smarx It makes sense, actually. Is there any other "easy" tool to make contract calls? Or do I have to get into actual code to try it?

Comment: Etherscan does it. I "verified" the contract code there, so you can go to https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x376b3433d9372be11745cbedf70edb0abb971fc2#writeContract and just call functions from that UI. You will need MetaMask, though.

Comment: That did it! It works! I guess there's some kind of bug or something with the Mist wallet. I'm new to the community, so I don't know if you should answer the question so that I can give you the reputation or what :)

Comment: I made an answer so you can accept it; thanks. I don't care much about the reputation points, but it's nice to keep the question from showing up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [transaction in question](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xca594ca981a3e492baa728cc26363f09552b9d21c40c54415fa52bb7392f96a5) has input data of `0x`, so it is *not* a call to `safeRetrieve` or any other function implemented in the contract.

When a transaction comes into a contract that doesn't match an existing function, the fallback function is invoked instead. In the case of a missing fallback function, as is the case here, the transaction is reverted.

Per the comments on the original question, this appears to be some sort of issue in Mist. Calling the function via Etherscan and MetaMask worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say for sure which part is problematic. As your function call is throwing the cause is most likely either of the function's two first lines which are checking for conditions with `require`. So either of those `require` statements throws.

One way to find out which one causes problems is to comment out the `require` statements one by one and see when it stops throwing errors.

You should also use a newer version of Solidity - the newest version is 0.5.7 (https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases) and you may be using something as old as 0.4.18. The language evolves rapidly and newer version is typically better.

Comment: I just tried and deployed another version of the contract but with both `assert` commented, and the result is the same: failed. The transaction with the new code is this one: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xb36d71fb8ad5a0b9d3198b63a6e9822f119b8b828629329ad0d3fb2002588898 . My guess is that the problem is with `transfer`, because remix also tells that the gast cost of `retrieveSafe` is high, potentially infinite.

Comment: Ah, read what smarx told you.